# Removing multiple reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have one question about removing multiple references. I have 3 schema models -> event, post and comment. Event store a references to post (one-to-many) and post store references to comments (one-to-many).

---

Event Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

const EventSchema = new Schema({
  organizer: { 
    type: ObjectId, 
    required: true, 
  }, 
  date: { 
    start: { 
      type: Date, 
      required: true, 
    }, 
    end: { 
      type: Date, 
      required: true, 
    }, 
  }, 
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  posts: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post',
  }],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

---

Post Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

const PostSchema = new Schema({
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
    required: true,
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  comments: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comment',
  }],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

---

Comment Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  author: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    id: {
      type: ObjectId,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

Now look at this situation: I'm removing an event so I need to remove also post (easy) and related comments(ups!). Here is my problem: how I can easily remove event with his all references (removing an event automatically removes post and related comments to this post)? I really don't have any idea. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

0) Read the event you want to delete

```
cont eventObj = Event.findOne({
  _id: myEventId,
})
```

1) Get all posts related to the event to delete

```
const posts = eventObj.posts;

const postObjs = Post.find({
  _id: {
    $in: posts,
  },
});
```

2) Get all comments related to the posts you want to delete

```
   const comments = postsObjs.reduce((tmp, x) => [
      ...tmp,
      ...x.comments,
   ], []);
```

3) Delete all comments

```
   Comments.remove({
     _id: {
       $in: comments,
     },
   });
```

4) Delete all posts

```
   Post.remove({
     _id: {
       $in: posts,
     },
   });
```

5) Delete the event

```
  Event.remove({
     _id: {
       $in: event,
     },
   });
```